# abbreviations with glossaries package - page two in header (book)

Tags: glossaries, fancyhdr

currently I am writing a document with some abbreviations. The package for the abbreviations is the glossaries:

```
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

I print the glossary with:

```
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]
```

The documentclass is a twoside book.
I already changed the headerstyle of the second page for the tableofcontents and the listoffigures, listoftables as well as the listoflistings (all with scshape).

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
      \@mkboth{%
        \scshape\contentsname}{\scshape\contentsname}
      }
      \@starttoc{toc}%
      \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  }
\makeatother
```

Now the abbreviations reached the second page and my problem occurs.

How can i change the headerstyle of the second abbreviations page so that it looks like the same as the other headers?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,toc]{glossaries}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
       \scshape\contentsname}{\scshape\contentsname}
    }%
   \@starttoc{toc}%
   \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  }
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\gls{a} \gls{b} \gls{c} \gls{d} \gls{e} \gls{f} \gls{g}
\gls{h} \gls{i} \gls{j} \gls{k} \gls{l} \gls{m} \gls{n}
\gls{o} \gls{p} \gls{q} \gls{r}

\newacronym{a}{a}{AAAAAAA}
\newacronym{b}{be}{BBBBBB}
\newacronym{c}{c}{CCCCCC}
\newacronym{d}{de}{DDDDDDD}
\newacronym{e}{e}{EEEEEE}
\newacronym{f}{ef}{FFFFFFF}
\newacronym{g}{ge}{GGGGGGGG}
\newacronym{h}{ha}{HHHHHHHH}
\newacronym{i}{i}{IIIIIIIIII}
\newacronym{j}{jot}{JJJJJJJ}
\newacronym{k}{ka}{KKKKKKKK}
\newacronym{l}{el}{LLLLLLLLLL}
\newacronym{m}{em}{MMMMMMMM}
\newacronym{n}{en}{NNNNNNNNN}
\newacronym{o}{o}{OOOOOOO}
\newacronym{p}{pe}{PPPPPPPPPP}
\newacronym{q}{qu}{QQQQQQQQQ}
\newacronym{r}{er}{RRRRRRRRR}

\end{document}
```

And here a screenshot of the differences. The missing \scshape

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the whole redefinition of `\tableofcontents` and add the typesetting command to the definition of the fancy header instead:

```
\fancyhead[RE]{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
```

By the way, for your example to compile it is necessary to move the acronym definitions to the beginning of the document, before using them.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,toc]{glossaries}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{a}{a}{AAAAAAA}
\newacronym{b}{be}{BBBBBB}
\newacronym{c}{c}{CCCCCC}
\newacronym{d}{de}{DDDDDDD}
\newacronym{e}{e}{EEEEEE}
\newacronym{f}{ef}{FFFFFFF}
\newacronym{g}{ge}{GGGGGGGG}
\newacronym{h}{ha}{HHHHHHHH}
\newacronym{i}{i}{IIIIIIIIII}
\newacronym{j}{jot}{JJJJJJJ}
\newacronym{k}{ka}{KKKKKKKK}
\newacronym{l}{el}{LLLLLLLLLL}
\newacronym{m}{em}{MMMMMMMM}
\newacronym{n}{en}{NNNNNNNNN}
\newacronym{o}{o}{OOOOOOO}
\newacronym{p}{pe}{PPPPPPPPPP}
\newacronym{q}{qu}{QQQQQQQQQ}
\newacronym{r}{er}{RRRRRRRRR}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\gls{a} \gls{b} \gls{c} \gls{d} \gls{e} \gls{f} \gls{g}
\gls{h} \gls{i} \gls{j} \gls{k} \gls{l} \gls{m} \gls{n}
\gls{o} \gls{p} \gls{q} \gls{r}

\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks. `\fancyhead[RE]{\scshape\leftmark}` and `\fancyhead[LO]{\scshape\rightmark}` solved my problem. But when I remove the redefinitions of tableofcontents the headings are only capital letters and not in scshape as you can see in your screenshots.

Comment: @dokukaefer Sorry, I overlooked it. `fancyhdr` offers a command `\nouppercase` that will deacticate the `makeuppercase` commands. See my corrected solution.